# Date Format to have Month as Text

Tags: formula, formula-field

So I'm trying to create a formula field that will take the termination date in our system and format the month into text but still keep the day and year in a number format. I have the following So for example if the date is 12/1/2023, I want it to return December 1, 2023.

fHCM2__E_End_Date__c is an date field.

This is what I have so far:

```
CASE(MONTH(DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c )),
1, "January",
2, "February",
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June",
7, "July",
8, "August",
9, "September",
10, "October",
11, "November",
12, "December",
"None") 
& TEXT(Day(DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c))  & "," 
& TEXT(Year(DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c )))
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the formula that you have? Are you getting an error ([edit] your question to include the error if you are)? If there isn't a syntax error, you'll need to give us information about the input you're using, the output you're getting, and the output you're expecting.

Comment: So I'm receiving the following syntax error: Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Syntax error. Missing ')' (Related field: Formula)

Answer (score 4):

When debugging formulas, the first thing you should *always* do is to format it [according to best practice](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_formula_best_practices.htm&type=5).

tl;dr: Put parts of formulas/functions on separate lines, and indent an extra level when you encounter an open paren.

In many cases, doing this will make it really easy to see issues. In this particular case, the issue is with

```
& TEXT(Day(DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c))  & ","
```

You've got close parens for `DATEVALUE` and `DAY`, but missed the one for `TEXT`

```
& TEXT(Day(DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c)))  & ","
```

Knowing how far to go in formula formatting is usually up to experience and personal taste. If we take things closer to the extreme though, the mistake becomes a bit more clear

```java
CASE(
    /* debugging step 1: Parenthesis for MONTH() and DATEVALUE() line up, so this is fine */
    MONTH(
        DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c )
    ),
    1, "January",
    2, "February",
    3, "March", 
    4, "April", 
    5, "May", 
    6, "June",
    7, "July",
    8, "August",
    9, "September",
    10, "October",
    11, "November",
    12, "December",
    "None"
)
/* debugging step 2: This section ends with some indentation, so something is wrong */ 

/* debugging step 6: The only thing left is this TEXT() function, so it must be */
/* the issue */
& TEXT(
    /* debugging step 5: DAY() and DATEVALUE() both have matching parens */
    /* So this is not the issue */
    Day(
        DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c)
    )  & "," 
    /* debugging step 4: This TEXT() has matching open + close parens */
    /* So this is not the issue */
    & TEXT(
        /* debugging step 3: YEAR() and DATEVALUE() both have matching open + close parens */
        /* So this is not the issue */
        Year(
            DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you. I have added the close parens at the end. I'm now getting the following syntax error when trying to save my formula field: Error: Invalid Data.
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Incorrect argument type for function 'DATEVALUE()'. (Related field: Formula)

Comment: @ALong This is why it's important to include as much detail in your questions as you can. What is the field type of `fHCM2__E_End_Date__c`? Is it a `Date` or a `Datetime`, or perhaps a `Text`? If it's a `Date`, then there's no need to use `DATEVALUE()`. If it's a text field, then it needs to match the format specified in [the documentation for `DATEVALUE()`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_datevalue.htm&type=5). You should edit your question to add this information.

Comment: Hello. fHCM2__E_End_Date__c is a date field. So I would not need to use date value anywhere in my formula?

Comment: @ALong correct. `DATEVALUE()` turns something that is not a date into a date. If your data is already a date, then there's obviously nothing to be converted. The [documentation on formula operators and functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) is a good thing to reference. It'll tell you what data types each function can take.

Comment: Thank you. So is this what I would want then: CASE(MONTH(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c )),
1, "January",
2, "February",
3, "March", 
4, "April", 
5, "May", 
6, "June",
7, "July",
8, "August",
9, "September",
10, "October",
11, "November",
12, "December",
"None") 
& TEXT(Day(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c))  & "," 
& TEXT(Year(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c ))

Answer (score 3):

```
& TEXT(Day(DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c))  & ","
```

Is missing a `)` near the end. Consider getting a syntax highlighter-enabled text editor, like VS Code, to make it easier to find these kinds of errors. The fix is as follows:

```
& TEXT(Day(DATEVALUE(fHCM2__E_End_Date__c)))  & ","
```

Here's an example of syntax highlighting in VS Code:

[image: Syntax Highlight Showing Missing Paranetheses]

As you can see, there's a red parentheses, which indicates a missing closing parentheses. The other colors help you visually pair up the parentheses, which is often helpful as well.